# Can anyone explain why source/dest packet captured by wireshark are in the same subnet ( DNS packet )

Tags: networking, dns, wireshark

I just know DNS will find the ip by query from ISP, but I don't know why it leads to my own network. So, anybody can you give me a reason why ?

Like there're 2 packets DNS request/response.

My request Source is 192.168.1.106 / Dest is 192.168.1.1
My response Source is 192.168.1.1 / Dest 192.168.1.106

Comment: Seems not to belong on StackOverflow since it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: 192.168.1.1 is most likely your Default Gateway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your 192.168.1.1 host has a DNS server. So when it receive DNS queries that he cannot resolve locally, he forward to an extenal DNS server ( ISP DNS server). 
They are 3 types of DNS query:
1. recursive query
2. iterative query
3. inverse queries